# DropboxServiceProvider api with .Net

Tags: asp.net, callback, dropbox, dropbox-api

Trying to use [Spring Net Social Dropbox](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-dropbox)

```
OAuthToken oauthToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.FetchRequestTokenAsync(callBackUrl, null).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Done");

OAuth1Parameters parameters = new OAuth1Parameters();

parameters.Add("locale", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag); // for a localized version of the authorization website
string authenticateUrl = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.BuildAuthorizeUrl(oauthToken.Value, parameters);
Console.WriteLine("Redirect user for authorization");
Process.Start(authenticateUrl);
```

After redirecting user to authenticate him with dropbox how to get the request access token as I am the request would be going to call back url.

Can I create new instance of OAuthToken and new instance of dropboxserviceprovider and use it to get the access token.

```
AuthorizedRequestToken requestToken = new AuthorizedRequestToken(oauthToken, null);

OAuthToken oauthAccessToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.ExchangeForAccessTokenAsync(requestToken, null).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Done");

/* API */
Console.WriteLine(oauthAccessToken.Value);
Console.WriteLine(oauthAccessToken.Secret);
IDropbox dropbox = dropboxServiceProvider.GetApi(oauthAccessToken.Value, oauthAccessToken.Secret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the access token in the session.
You can create a DropboxServiceProvider any time you need, what's important is the oauth access token.
Take a look to the MVC quickstart provided in the package.